# Updatable Views in Entity Framework 5/6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have several Views that are updatable according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx.

All of my views follow the specifications in the afformentioned article. I have verified in SQL Management Studio that the views can be updated, inserted to, and deleted from.

The research I have done has led me to two options to make the views in my Entity Framework 5/6 Model updatable:

1. Remove the  tag from each view, however, any work
   done in MyContext.edmx is overwritten when updating the context from
   the database. This means that this solution isn't very viable for my
   project.
2. Adding a insert, update, and delete stored procedure for each
   view and mapping these in the designer. I don't particularly like
   the idea of having to create this many stored procedures.

Is there any easy way to tell EF5 OR EF6 that the views can be added to/updated/deleted from that will not be wiped out when running subsequent "Update Model from Database" commands without writing stored procedures for each entry method(insert, update, delete)  on each view?

Answer (score 8):

I would think that your easiest method, would be to change the definition of your EntitySet in your StorageModel to tell it to regard it as a table, as opposed to a database-view.

Looking at the XML definition, where it says

```
<EntitySet Name="Products" store:Type="Views" ..
```

you change that to

```
<EntitySet Name="Products" store:Type="Tables" ..
```

(Note the "Products" is just an example)
This should be in your .edmx file.
See pg 44, Lerman, "Programming Entity Framework", 2nd Ed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like your example code may be missing, but I do get what you are trying to say. I will look into your suggestion.

Comment: My bad - I didn't notice that the xml brackets would make the text disappear like that.

Comment: After some testing this violates one of my constraints, "not be wiped out when running subsequent "Update Model from Database" commands". When performing an update the wizard thinks the View is now a table and requests to Add my view again in order to receive the changes. I ignored the request and ran the update. Afterwards I get an error stating that my view (converted to a table) is not mapped and the view I need to map it to is now missing. That said I also received errors just after switching it from type Views to Tables.

Comment: Remember - you have several, very distinct approaches that you can take when implementing EF. "Model-first", or "database-first", for example. Which I assume you already know. When we then go in the opposite direction, it squawks. Personally, I like the stored-proc method, because I usually find these can be made significantly more efficient, plus you can double-check some of the argument-values before insertion.

Comment: Don't forget to set key if the model key is not detected correctly.
You can see this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/09/01/tip-34-how-to-work-with-updatable-views.aspx) for a described sample.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using .edmx you go with poco classes and use dbcontext and modelbuilder class for mapping its very lightweight or its not updated every time whenever you update the database . its very efficient and scaleble

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get primary key from view and do your update statement using the primary key. Just a way to work around.